# Query rows having maximum value in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho um problema com uma `query` em um banco `Oracle` em uma tabela com 3 colunas:

> ID_Loja | Canal | Valor_Venda

Há a possibilidade de ter mais de uma venda por loja e eu quero saber qual o canal atribuido à loja baseado na quantidade de vendas que cada loja teve conforme o exemplo abaixo. Nesse caso, eu quero que a query apenas retorne a linha que contém o canal "A" uma vez que nesse caso ocorreram 5 vendas vs 4 vendas para a mesma loja com classificação diferente.

ID_Loja: 1

Canal: A

Count(Valor_Venda): 5

ID_Loja: 1

Canal: B

Count(Valor_Venda): 4

Até o momento, fiz apenas a `query` que traz a quantidade de vendas por loja/canal, porém não consegui trazer apenas a combinação que possui mais vendas por loja/canal apenas.

```
SELECT

ID_Loja, Canal, COUNT(Valor_Venda)

FROM Vendas

GROUP BY ID_loja, Canal
```

Conseguem me ajudar?

Comment: Leandro, não entendi muito bem oque precisa. Você quer trazer somente a loja com mais vendas? Todas as outras lojas não devem aparecer no resultado?

Comment: Entendi oque você precisa, o canal não deve repetir. Se a loja 1 vendeu 10 no canal "A" e a loja 2 vendeu 5 pro mesmo canal, apenas a `Loja 1` deverá aparecer.

Answer (score 1):

No exemplo abaixo veja que o Canal **A** e o Canal **B** aparecem pra mais de uma loja, mas apenas a loja que vendeu mais pra esse canal será mostrada:

```
WITH table_(ID_Loja, Canal, Valor_Venda) as (
    select 1, 'A', 120 from dual union all
    select 2, 'y', 300 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A', 250 from dual union all
    select 3, 'z', 100 from dual union all
    select 3, 'z', 170 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A', 200 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A', 150 from dual union all
    select 3, 'A', 100 from dual union all
    select 3, 'A', 170 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A', 200 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A', 150 from dual union all
    select 4, 'B', 150 from dual union all
    select 3, 'B', 100 from dual union all
    select 4, 'B', 170 from dual union all
    select 4, 'B', 200 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A', 150 from dual union all
    select 3, 'z', 130 from dual )

Select * from (
  SELECT
  ID_Loja, Canal, COUNT(Valor_Venda) as qtdeVenda,
  rank() over (partition by ID_Loja order by COUNT(Valor_Venda) desc) rnk
  FROM table_
  Group By ID_Loja, Canal) query
where query.rnk = 1;
```

[Veja mais sobre a função rank do oracle.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm)