# Retornar linhas com o maior valor em uma coluna

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho um problema com uma *query* em um banco Oracle em uma tabela com 3 colunas:

`ID_Loja | Canal | Valor_Venda`

Há a possibilidade de ter mais de uma venda por loja e eu quero saber qual o canal atribuído à loja baseado na quantidade de vendas que cada loja teve conforme o exemplo abaixo. Nesse caso, eu quero que a *query* apenas retorne a linha que contém o canal "A" uma vez que nesse caso ocorreram 5 vendas vs 4 vendas para a mesma loja com classificação diferente.

```
           ID_Loja: 1
             Canal: A
Count(Valor_Venda): 5

           ID_Loja: 1
             Canal: B
Count(Valor_Venda): 4
```

Até o momento, fiz apenas a *query* que traz a quantidade de vendas por loja/canal, porém não consegui trazer apenas a combinação que possui mais vendas por loja/canal apenas.

```
SELECT ID_Loja, Canal, COUNT(Valor_Venda)
FROM Vendas
GROUP BY ID_loja, Canal
```

Comment: [Duplicada exata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206364/query-rows-having-maximum-value-in-a-column). Acabei de responder sua questão na sua pergunta anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não tenho o Oracle aqui, mas tente usar uma tabela temporária, na sintaxe do postgreSQL ficou assim:

```
with temp as (select 
    f.ID_Loja,
    f.Canal,
    count(*) as qtd
    from Vendas f
    group by f.Canal,f.ID_Loja )

select  distinct
f.ID_Loja,
t.Canal,
t.qtd
from Vendas f 
inner join temp t on t.ID_Loja = f.ID_Loja and t.qtd = (select max(qtd) from temp x where x.ID_Loja = t.ID_Loja)
order by t.qtd desc
```

Comment: Nesse caso, como há 2 canais diferentes para a mesma loja, sua query irá retornar as 2 linhas. No caso eu preciso que retorne somente a linha que possui o maior número de vendas por loja e seu canal respectivo, assim excluindo a linha da loja que tem o canal "B"

Comment: Editei a resposta, mas como não tenho o Oracle, talvez não seja a mesma sintaxe do postgreSQL, qualquer coisa, tente usar o http://sqlfiddle.com/ para nos mostrar o schema e a query

Comment: Obs. Optei por essa forma, porque se houver duas lojas com a mesma quantidade em dois canais, esses irão aparecer no resultado também